# Serializing long Array in MySQL text type field and increasing the size of text type.

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, serialization

I created a Rails app that uses MySQL DB. I need to save a long Array of Ids to one of the table's field (users) in Notification table.

```
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| status     | int(11)  | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| message    | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| users      | text     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So in my Notification model:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :users, Array
end
```

Now the problem is that I can't save more than ~64kb, a lot of users are not saved.

How am I supposed to increase the size of text?

Comment: Ok seems the trick was to change the type to mediumtext using : ALTER TABLE notifications MODIFY users MEDIUMTEXT ;

Comment: post the answer to your question. then select it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems the trick was to change the type to MEDIUMTEXT:

```
ALTER TABLE notifications MODIFY users MEDIUMTEXT
```

If you are using Rails you can set it up in the migration file by changing the limit option:

```
add_column :notifications, :users, :text, :limit => 16777215
```